# How to automatically turn off external hard-drive connected to Time Capsule when idle?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, time-capsule

I have a [5th generation AirPort Time Capsule (3TB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Time_Capsule) with an additional [G-DRIVE GEN4 (3TB)](http://www.g-technology.com/products/g-drive) external hard-drive attached to it. The external hard-drive has an on/off switch.

Is it possible- and how can I make it so that the external hard-drive turns off or hibernates after a period of being idle, without turning off the power switch? I don't want it to be always active.

The external hard-drive is not used as a Time Machine backup drive; I'm only using it as a network share/network-attached storage, so that we can share files more easily within the household.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. The Time Capsule does not supported that feature.

Comment: I asked Apple support and the hard-drive manufacturer, and they both said the same thing. Doesn't seem like it's possible.